# Dynamic Routing witihin vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, kubernetes, dynamic, routes, assets

in a current project I have a problem understanding (and configuring) routing within my vue.js app.

**Our Setup**

We have a setup, where for each Pull Request in our repos a new Snapshot Environment is created. This environment is one namespace within a kubernetes Cluster. All services in a current develop state are deployed with the new "snapshot" version of the service that triggered the CICD pipeline. To have a clear route for each snapshot environment, we use the namespace as part of the URL (https://HOST/NAMESPACE/APP/paths)

**Our Problem**

As you can see, the URL is highly dynamic, but currently, we could just build the container with the path and be happy. Thats our current setup. Unfortunately, we want the possibility, to deploy each and every container image on every HOST as well as every NAMESPACE, those parts are only known at runtime, not in the CICD Pipeline.

Is there any way to handle such a scenario with vue.js. I have basically every freedom to edit the app as well as the container, but can't change the way we want to host our app. Currently we build the App on the cluster and inject the NAMESPACE, which was the "easiest" way to do this. But if there is any other way, I would love to not have the build and run step together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the dependency the application has on the full URL/path? Normally you avoid specifying full URLs in the UI build so it can be hosted anywhere like your setup requires.

Comment: Of course, in vue i have to specify the publicPath, which (if I understand correctly) would be /NAMESPACE/APP. this would be needed in a history based routing approach. In a hash based one, i tried to configure the publicPath with ./ or an relative alternative. 

The main problem are the assets (transpiled js, images, ...) not really routing within the app or any service